# How to fix "The multi-part identifier ....could not be bound"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have certain code which throws this error and I have declared it in the functionality itself

```
 IF @Functionality='UserDetails'                                        
 BEGIN                                        

   SELECT TOP 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY USR.USERBADGENO ASC) AS SNO, 
         USR.USERBADGENO,
         USR.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + USR.LASTNAME AS USERNAME,
         ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),LST.LASTLOGIN), 'NO LOGS FOUND') AS LASTACCESSED,
         APP.NAME AS APPNAME,
         URD.USERROLECODE 
   FROM USERMASTER USR                                         
   INNER JOIN USERROLEDETAILS URD 
     ON  URD.USERROLECODE = USR.USERROLE                                        
   INNER JOIN APPLICATIONS1 APP 
     ON APP.APPID = URD.APPID                     
   LEFT JOIN LASTLOGINDETAILS LST 
     ON LST.USERID = USR.USERBADGENO 
     AND LST.APPID = APP.APPID                                      
   WHERE APP.APPID = @APPID 
   AND URD.USERROLECODE = @USERROLE   
   ORDER BY LST.LASTLOGIN DESC                                      

 END
```

I expect the output to display the records of last three months in the application in grid view

Complete error message:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier "LST.LASTLOGIN" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier "APP.NAME" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier "URD.USERROLECODE" could not be bound.

Comment: Please mention the *entire* error message and the columns of the table you are trying to read from. Probably you've made an easy mistake.

Comment: Line breaks and white space make for much more readable code too. Putting the majority of your statement on a single line makes this even harder to debug without the full error.

Comment: The error messages are:

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "LST.LASTLOGIN" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "APP.NAME" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "URD.USERROLECODE" could not be bound.

Comment: columns of the table are : ID, USERBADGENO, USERROLE,COUNTRY,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,MIDDLENAME,EMAILID,MOBILE,ISACTIVE,SERVICECOMPANY,CREATEDBY,UPDATEDBY,CREATEDON,UPDATEDON,GHRSID,WINDOWSID,ITSMTICKETNO,KINDOFUSER

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. There is no column `NAME` in your table `APPLICATIONS1`, and no column `LASTLOGIN` in table `LASTLOGINDETAILS`, etc.

Comment: Also, include the DDL of your tables in your question; not a list of random columns in a comment (the latter isn't helpful to us).

Comment: But the names exist in the table

Comment: The only DDL is Alter

Comment: *"But the names exist in the table"* they clearly don't, as the error is telling us otherwise. Without the DDL there's little else we can suggest.

Comment: There isn't enough information for anyone to debug that for you. We need to see the table definitions to do that. And even then thats only going to confirm what we already know, being that the *cause* of that error is that the columns don't exist in the tables you are trying to query them from.

Comment: Your query assumes that the tables mentioned are in the current database for the connection and that they are members of either the current user's default schema or of the dbo schema. Verify your assumptions. Your don't tag any development tool other than sql server, so in what context does this script execute? Is it part of a larger script that creates or alters the tables mentioned?

Comment: @RufeenaJack, you will get the error if you added to columns in the same batch as the query. The entire batch is compiled against the existing table definition before the `ALTER` DDL statement is executed.

Answer (score 1):

The

> Error The multi-part identifier xxxxxx could not be bound

is thrown when the column which you have given in the query does not exist. When the compiler tries to compile the query, it will search for that column and since the Column does not exists, the query won't be compiled. So Please make sure that you have spelled the column names correctly. It may also occur if you have given the wrong alias name,

eg:

I have a Column UserName in User Table and Have EmployeeName in Employee table. So this query will work

```
SELECT UserName FROM User
SELECT EmployeeName FROM Employee
```

But instead, If I try the below it will fail

```
SELECT UserName FROM Employee
SELECT EmployeeName FROM User
```

So Please make sure that the names are spelled correctly